# XMPPConnection closed during file transfer from Android to Spark

Tags: android, xmpp, file-transfer, smack

My app crashes after the user on Spark accepts the file for transfer. Can anyone help me find out why this happens?

My logcat :

```
D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='myRecipient@serverip/Spark' id='87PqQ-26' type='set'><si xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/si' id='jsi_3460263582698459885' mime-type='image/jpeg' profile='http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer'><file xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer" name="IMG_20151105_142957.jpg" size="1942601" ><desc>test_file</desc></file><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='form'><field var='stream-method' type='list-single'><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value></option><option><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></option></field></x></feature></si></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <message id="6Toac-405" to="me@serverip" from="myRecipient@serverip/Spark" type="chat"><thread>k28Mi99</thread><active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/></message>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq id="87PqQ-26" to="me@serverip/Smack" from="myRecipient@serverip/Spark" type="result"><si xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"><feature xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/feature-neg"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="stream-method"><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams</value><value>http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb</value></field></x></feature></si></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='myRecipient@serverip/Spark' id='87PqQ-29' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <message id="6Toac-406" to="me@serverip" from="myRecipient@serverip/Spark" type="chat"><thread>k28Mi100</thread><inactive xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/></message><message id="6Toac-407" to="me@serverip" from="myRecipient@serverip/Spark" type="chat"><thread>k28Mi101</thread><active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/></message>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq id="87PqQ-29" to="me@server/Smack" type="result" from="myRecipient@serverip/Spark"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="client" name="Smack" type="pc"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/><feature var="urn:xmpp:tmp:jingle"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer"/><feature var="urn:xmpp:ping"/><feature var="jabber:iq:last"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/commands"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><feature var="http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html#ns"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='serverip' id='87PqQ-33' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="87PqQ-33" from="serverip" to="me@serverip/Smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"><item jid="pubsub.serverip" name="Publish-Subscribe service"/><item jid="search.serverip" name="User Search"/><item jid="proxy.serverip" name="Socks 5 Bytestreams Proxy"/><item jid="conference.serverip" name="Public Chatrooms"/></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='pubsub.serverip' id='87PqQ-35' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="87PqQ-35" from="pubsub.serverip" to="me@serverip/Smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="pubsub" name="Publish-Subscribe service" type="service"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#access-open"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#collections"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#config-node"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-and-configure"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#create-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#delete-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#get-pending"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#instant-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#item-ids"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#meta-data"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#modify-affiliations"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#manage-subscriptions"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#multi-subscribe"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#outcast-affiliation"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#persistent-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#presence-notifications"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publish"/><
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#publisher-affiliation"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#purge-nodes"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retract-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-affiliations"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-default"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-items"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#retrieve-subscriptions"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscribe"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#subscription-options"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='search.serverip' id='87PqQ-37' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="87PqQ-37" from="search.serverip" to="me@serverip/Smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="directory" type="user" name="User Search"/><feature var="jabber:iq:search"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"/></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='proxy.serverip' id='87PqQ-39' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="87PqQ-39" from="proxy.serverip" to="me@serverip/Smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="proxy" name="SOCKS5 Bytestreams Service" type="bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='conference.serverip' id='87PqQ-41' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="87PqQ-41" from="conference.serverip" to="me@serverip/Smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"><identity category="conference" name="Public Chatrooms" type="text"/><identity category="directory" name="Public Chatroom Search" type="chatroom"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"/><feature var="jabber:iq:search"/><feature var="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"/></query></iq>
I/System.out﹕ tcp port:7777
D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=128KB
D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=31: interp stack at 0x6308b000
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=31: created from interp
D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=31: notify debugger
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=31 (Thread-4359): calling run()
D/SMACK﹕ SENT (0): <iq to='proxy.serverip' id='87PqQ-43' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams'/></iq>
D/SMACK﹕ RECV (0): <iq type="result" id="87PqQ-43" from="proxy.serverip" to="me@serverip/Smack"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams"><streamhost jid="proxy.175.139.183.204" port="7777"/></query></iq>
W/XMPPTCPConnection﹕ shutdownDone was not marked as successful by the writer thread
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkForResponse(SynchronizationPoint.java:253)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.SynchronizationPoint.checkIfSuccessOrWait(SynchronizationPoint.java:146)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.shutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1278)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.shutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:503)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.instantShutdown(XMPPTCPConnection.java:492)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.notifyConnectionError(XMPPTCPConnection.java:872)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.access$2800(XMPPTCPConnection.java:140)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.writePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1428)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.access$2900(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1179)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1227)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[55522]
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=14: exiting
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=14: bye!
I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:55522]
W/AbstractXMPPConnection﹕ Connection closed with error
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.LazyStringBuilder.length(LazyStringBuilder.java:72)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.LazyStringBuilder.toString(LazyStringBuilder.java:100)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.XmlStringBuilder.toString(XmlStringBuilder.java:344)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.writePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1377)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.access$2900(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1179)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1227)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
D/SMACK﹕ XMPPConnection closed due to an exception (0)
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.LazyStringBuilder.length(LazyStringBuilder.java:72)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.LazyStringBuilder.toString(LazyStringBuilder.java:100)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.XmlStringBuilder.toString(XmlStringBuilder.java:344)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.writePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1377)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.access$2900(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1179)
W/System.err﹕ at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1227)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: exiting
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: bye!
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=30: exiting
D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=30: bye!
```

ProviderManager :

```
private void setupXMPP()
    {
        // must run in thread else got error
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run()
        {
            boolean makeConnectionSuccess = buildConnection();

            if(makeConnectionSuccess)
            {
                ProviderManager.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());
                ProviderManager.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
                ProviderManager.addIQProvider("open", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new OpenIQProvider());
                ProviderManager.addIQProvider("close", "http://jabber.org/protocol/ibb", new CloseIQProvider());
                ProviderManager.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
                ProviderManager.addIQProvider("query","http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
                XMPPConn.getInstance().setXMPPConn(connection);

                android.os.Message msg = connFinishHandler.obtainMessage();
                connFinishHandler.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Login :

```
public String LoginAndSetting(String username, String password)
    {
    String errorMsg = "ok";
    usernameTempSave = username;
    passwordTempSave = password;

    boolean loginSuccess = userlogin();        //user login

    if(loginSuccess)
    {
        usernameSave = usernameTempSave;

        setConnection();    //receiver register
        keepAlive();        //ping manager register
        reenterGroupChat();


        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("username", usernameTempSave);
        editor.putString("password", passwordTempSave);
        editor.apply();

        android.os.Message msg = loginFinishHandler.obtainMessage();
        loginFinishHandler.handleMessage(msg);
    }
    else
    {
        errorMsg = "Error password or username";
    }
    return errorMsg;
}

public boolean userlogin()
    {
    boolean loginSuccess  = true;
    if (connection != null)
    {
        //change user login username check

        try {
            boolean isConnected = connection.isConnected();

            if(isConnected)
            {
                SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
                SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");

                connection.login(usernameTempSave,passwordTempSave);;
            }
            else
            {
                SASLAuthentication.unBlacklistSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
                SASLAuthentication.blacklistSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5");

                connection.connect().login(usernameTempSave,passwordTempSave);;
            }

            loginSuccess = true;
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            loginSuccess = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            loginSuccess = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            loginSuccess = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //findUser("");
    return loginSuccess;
}
```

Select file then transfer :

```
private  void selectImage()
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/storage/sdcard1/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151105_142957.jpg");

    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    selectedImagePath = "/storage/sdcard1/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20151105_142957.jpg";
    System.out.println(selectedImagePath);
    fileTransfer(selectedImagePath);
}

public void fileTransfer(String filenameWithPath) {

    FileTransferManager manager = FileTransferManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(friendId + "@serverip/Spark");

    File file = new File(filenameWithPath);

    try {
        transfer.sendFile(file, "test_file");
    } catch (SmackException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (!transfer.isDone()) {
        if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!!! " + transfer.getError());
        } else if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)
                || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused)) {
            System.out.println("Cancelled!!! " + transfer.getError());
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.refused) || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.error)
            || transfer.getStatus().equals(FileTransfer.Status.cancelled)) {
        System.out.println("refused cancelled error " + transfer.getError());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Success");
    }
}
```

What I know is that a NullPointerException is returned when trying to write the xml to send to the server side. What I dont know is why it will return null and because it returns null, it causes my XMPPConnection connection to close.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: single user logged in.. i mean for single session for one user name ? if possible thn pls post your code for connection , login and file transfer

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want to see so.. if it isn't please specify more cause I'm new at this

Comment: 1 more thing I noticed is that right before the XMPPTCPConnection closed. In the received xml, in the <streamhost> there seems to be a missing host="serverIP"...